# mysql query in java with MBROVERLAP

Tags: java, mysql

I try to run this mysql query and I have this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @r2 =
>   GeomFromText('Polygon((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))'); select
>   MBROVERLAPS(@r1' at line 2

Code:

```
public String getoverlap(Rectangle recA, Rectangle recB){
    String result = "-1";
    String query;

    query =    
            "SET @r1 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1, 5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\');\n" +
            "SET @r2 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\');\n" +
           "select MBROVERLAPS(@r1,@r2);" ;

     System.out.println("query--:\n "+query);


     try {
        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet  rs = this.statement.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("kkk:" +rs.toString());

        if(rs!=null){
            result = rs.getString("MBROVERLAPS(@r1,@r2)");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Debug: lathos sthn getoverlap");
        }

         statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("debug: sqlEcxeption");
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

     return result;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC API does *not* emulate your typical SQL client - you cannot merge multiple statements together in the way you have. Specifically, this query:

```
query =    
    "SET @r1 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1, 5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\');\n" +
    "SET @r2 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\');\n" +
    "select MBROVERLAPS(@r1,@r2);" ;
```

Needs to be split up, with each statement being run separately. Illustrated, by running each part directly via the statement:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("SET @r1 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1, 5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\')";
statement.executeQuery("SET @r2 = GeomFromText(\'Polygon((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))\')");
ResultSet  rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MBROVERLAPS(@r1,@r2)");
System.out.println(rs.toString());
```

A dead giveaway is that you should never have delimiting semi-colons in your JDBC query strings.